# YouTube iframe doesn't work on Samsung S2 I9100G

Tags: android, api, iframe, youtube, embed

I have an Android app which using YouTube iframe tag to embed videos. It's working in most of the mobile (including Samsung S2 I9100) but today when i tried to test the app on Samsung Galaxy S2 I9100**G** it shows a gray screen with a reel button at the center! Anyone have any idea on how to fix this?

```
WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
WebSettings webViewSettings = webview.getSettings();webViewSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
            webViewSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webViewSettings.setPluginsEnabled(true);
            webViewSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            webViewSettings.setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
```

Iframe Tag:

```
<iframe class="youtube-player" type="text/html" "width="420" height="250" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/348fjdsf8?fs=0&autoplay=1" "frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="false">
```

Answer (score 1):

You do this by using the translate3d transform method. The code that worked for me follows:
HTML

```
<div class="animClass">
    <iframe width="100%" height="58%" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/-1UIBTve4dI?rel=0&;&autoplay=0&controls=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.animClass {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

http://www.telerik.com/forums/youtube-video-audio-but-no-video#JPiN4piN6U6eITVmd0hz9A